# Mixing position and names in purrr map input

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

The `purrr::map` function provides some shortcuts for selecting list elements: you can use a position by providing an integer, or a name by providing a string. An example [here](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls02_map-extraction-advanced.html#vector_input_to_extraction_shortcuts) indicates that you can use a vector to deal with nested list elements. For example,

```
library(purrr)
library(repurrrsive) #includes example list data
gh_repos %>% map_chr(., c(1, 3))
```

navigates within each first position to retrieve and return the third list element.

Yet, when I tried to mix input using a position and name, it returns an error:

```
gh_repos %>% map_chr(., c(1, "full_name"))
#Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

The syntax can be represented several other ways to return the same results:

```
gh_repos %>% map_chr(c(1,3)) #Shown above
gh_repos %>% map(1) %>% map_chr("full_name")
gh_repos %>% map_chr(~pluck(.x, 1, "full_name"))
```

The last option was a discovery I made that approaches mixed inputs. I recognize that the mixed vectorized input is of a different class because it includes characters. Is this the reason it produces an error? What changes can I make to use mixed position and name inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the different data classes. When you use `c()`, everything gets coerced to the same atomic type . So `c(1, "full_name")` is turned into `c("1", "full_name")` which is a character vector. And the first list doesn't have a named element with the name `"1"`. If you want to have mixed classes in R, you generally use lists. And it appears that `map` supports lists. For example

```
gh_repos %>% map_chr(list(1, "full_name"))
# [1] "gaborcsardi/after"   "jennybc/2013-11_sfu" "jtleek/advdatasci"   "juliasilge/2016-14" 
# [5] "leeper/ampolcourse"  "masalmon/aqi_pdf"
```